# css finds the images but cant load them up into a preview

Tags: java, jquery, html, css, image

I linked my stylesheet to my base html file.

```
 <title> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

and when i click go to link it goes to the right file. i can change the background color and all of the other margins. but when i insert a url the css seems to find the picture but doesnt load up to the html and if i click preview non of the images does load.

```
 picture {
 width: 984px;
 height: 148px;
 background-image:url(img/header.jpg/);
```

Comment: what is picture? class or id?

Comment: It would help if you provided the HTML code and the folder structure of your project. Anyway, you may have a typo in "img/header.jpg/". Try removing the ending extra slash.

Comment: Is your CSS file in a 'css' subdirectory? Then you have to give the URL as `../img/header.jpg`, because it has to be relative to the CSS file. And of course the two other comments before.

Comment: its not a typo. the css file stands in the same map than the html file

Comment: and its not the css file because if i hover over url(img/header/jpg) i can see the picture.

Comment: @user2742028 Edit your question, make sure the code reflects your actual issue, as it is now it's full of errors, read the comments and answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

link your css under header tag not title tag as title tag is referring to Website Title.

```
<header>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</header>
```

and the typo mentioned in comments, and ensure your destination is correct.]

p/s (typo)

```
picture{
    background-image:url(img/header.jpg);
}
```

Comment: its really weird because i can just change the background color of the div but i cant put i picture in it.

Comment: now only that picture loads. its better but can you explain where the typo was?

Comment: #leftcol_bottom {
 background-image: url(/img/leftcol_bottom.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 width: 220px;
 height: 13px;
 margin-bottom: 13px;

it was a typo. and now that picture loads. but the rest doesnt.. this is just another example of a linked div. is there something wrong with this one too because this one doesnt even link to the image if i hover over it.

Comment: the typo is the "/" behind the header.jpg. 
header.jpg should be your file type, so "/" is behind will corrupted the file name type. "/" usually is using for verify folder. Do all the changes to all the divs, the you should have all picture showing.

Answer (score 0):

Like this below code `paste` in your `html`

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>TEST</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="etbplaza.nl/css/style_basic.css"; />
</head>
<body>
<div class="picture"> your code hre </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.picture {
 width: 984px;
 height: 148px;
 background-image:url(img/header.jpg/);
```

Comment: why do you link the html to a website?

Comment: i use localhost so the correct route is /root/formaten/style.css

Answer (score 0):

This might be a typo:

```
picture {
 width: 984px;
 height: 148px;
 background-image:url(img/header.jpg/);
```

picture has no  class nor id selector which might causing the problem and/or may be try to use `url('img/header.jpg');` within quotes. or `url('../img/header.jpg')` but we don't know where is the image is located.

Also try this:

1. Inspect Element
2. hover over the path and see is there the path is being loaded if yes
   your image would show there

[See this technique](http://css-tricks.com/css-image-replacement/)

Answer (score 0):

change `background-image:url(img/header.jpg/);` to `background-image:url(img/header.jpg);`               also make sure the `/path/to/file` is correct and if picture is a div class then it will be like `.picture` in your css

Answer (score 0):

```
you have to use the css as in the form of class or id and try the code as

.picture {
 width: 984px;
 height: 148px;
 background-image:url(img/header.jpg);
}

or as id 

#picture {
 width: 984px;
 height: 148px;
 background-image:url(img/header.jpg);
}

surly you got the preview of the Image to your HTML page. 
Please check the path of css file is correct or not.
```